# How to bypass failed ansible tasks, but still report them as failed?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook, which just runs a series of checks on my inventory, and I want to see how many failed on each host.

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: root

  vars:
    CHECKSLIST:
      - check1
      - check2
      - check3  

  tasks:
  - name: Check All
    include_tasks: "check_{{ item }}.yml"
    with_items: "{{ CHECKSLIST }}"
```

All check task files look like this

```
---

- block:
  - name: check backups
    command: /usr/checks/check_backups
    changed_when: False
    register: OUTPUT_CHECK_backups
    tags: backups
```

However in this way, if the first check on a host fails, the rest of the checks won't be run at all.

I could put ignore_errors:yes on each individual check task, but then the Play Recap will report that all was checked OK on that host.

Is there a way to avoid a failed task blocking all other tasks, and still get a proper play recap of all failed tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I've put the following "dummy" rescue block in each task

---

```
- block:
  - name: check backups
    command: /usr/nagios/plugins/check_backups
    changed_when: False
    register: OUTPUT_CHECK_backups
    tags: backups
  rescue:
    - fail:
      failed_when: false
```

But I'm not sure if there's a "proper" way to do this instead.

Answer (score 1):

Rescuable erros can be handled by [rescue](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#error-handling). In this case "*failed_when: false*" is not needed to proceed, I think.

```
- block:
    - name: check backups
      command: /usr/checks/check_backups
      register: OUTPUT_CHECK_backups
  rescue:
    - debug: var=OUTPUT_CHECK_backups
  tags: backups
```

For example to include_tasks check[1-3].yml

```
- block:
    - command: /bin/false
      register: result
  rescue:
    - debug: msg="check1 failed."
    - debug: var=result
```

gives (grep msg:)

```
msg: non-zero return code
msg: check1 failed.
  msg: non-zero return code
msg: non-zero return code
msg: check2 failed.
  msg: non-zero return code
msg: non-zero return code
msg: check3 failed.
msg: non-zero return code
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using this method as well as a workaround (see my own answer).  In fact I just now improved it so that rather than a debug, I use a rescue to save a hostlist of the hosts where a particular check failed